# How do I find elements when given tensors and position values?

Tags: python, pytorch, element, tensor

Assume that the tensor is given as

```
tensor = torch.Tensor([[[1, 0, 0, 7], [0, 1, 0, 4], [3, 0, 9, 0]]])
```

I found the position of the zero value in the tensor.

```
a = (tensor == 0).nonzero(as_tuple=False)
```

Here is the result:

```
tensor([[0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 2],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 2, 1],
        [0, 2, 3]])
```

I want to find the element in the tensor again using the following result:
As expected, all results should return 0.

How do I do this?

Comment: Just use the returned indices as indices of the original tensor?

Comment: Yes, I want to use the returned result to find an element again in the tensor value in the tensor variable.

Comment: The result should be all zeros.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```py
tensor = torch.Tensor([[[1, 0, 0, 7], [0, 1, 0, 4], [3, 0, 9, 0]]])

# note change to `as_tuple=True` here
a = (tensor == 0).nonzero(as_tuple=True)

tensor[a]
# ==> tensor([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

Indexing in pytorch works (mostly!) the same as in numpy, hence the link to the numpy documentation above.

Comment: Thanks to your help, I was able to solve this problem.